# Grails screen appears blank - Only in deployed version

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

The Grails system with which we've been working fine for several months now has a problem whereby the `/login/auth` page appears blank.

The problem with the build only occurs on a deployed Tomcat or standalone system and not on local development machines where it works fine. There is no error appearing on the console at all. 
The Network tab in Chrome shows a `404 error`. We've put console debug messages in the `auth()` method within `LoginController` and these are not showing up.

In intellij Idea works fine, after generate the `.war` file (`./gradlew assemble`) the system not work.

Comment: It would be hard to get help on this kind of problem without providing the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What happens when you try to access a page directly? Do you see log entries in in localhost_access* logs?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you get an 404 error, you should check all of the config files e.g. database settings. Somewhere must be a difference in those settings. Usually it is database connection which causes such kind of errors.
```

You can also check Catalina.log in the Tomcat server directory to find errors.

Comment: After some checks I came to the conclusion that they are the "assets", they are not being accessed when the application is executed by the .war file, but works correctly by intellij idea. No solution yet.